# PNChart-swift not working

Tags: swift, git

I wanna use some charts in my swift project, actually I was using PNChart before, but now I need to move on to PNChart-swift.

https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart-Swift

as the readme saids I added some lines in Podfile, and I

`pod install`

then I get "no such module PNChart-swift"

I think Pod is cloning the wrong Codes from the PNChart-swift repository.

Is there any way I can clone the codes and use as the library without using Pod?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manual installation you could just download the repo as zipfile and than drag the .xcodeproj file into your project.

This will create the required reference so that you can use it.

You may also need to add it as embedded framework in your project settings.

Comment: You mean I should drag the .xcodeproj directly to xcode, which is opened by project.xcworkspace?

Comment: drag the frameworks .xcodeproj file into your project (you may want to create a group "frameworks" or something like that and drop it into this group to keep your project's structure clean :) Also if you drag-and-dropped it into your project you still may need to "import" it in the classes where you want to use it.